# How to find the root cause of "Element odoo has extra content: data"

Tags: python, xml, odoo, relaxng

The error message

> "Element odoo has extra content: data"

may be generated if an xml file such as a view fails to validate against the RELAXNG schema file `odoo/odoo/import_xml.rng`. Unforunately it isn't very specific.  For example, this file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
  <data>

    <record id="record_id" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">foo.bar.form</field>
      <field name="model">baz.model</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="My Form">
          <sheet>
            <group>
              <field name="my_field"/>
          </group>
          </sheet>
        </form>
      </field>
    </record>

    <act_window id="action_quux" name="My Action" res_model="baz.model" view_model="form"/>

  </data>
</odoo>
```

will generate the message when validated, but there is no indication that the specific problem is that `view_model` should be `view_mode`. Is there a way to get a better error message?

Comment: There is no attribute named `view_model`, but you can use `view_mode` (default= tree,form ).  Check the [window actions](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/master/developer/reference/backend/actions.html#window-actions-ir-actions-act-window) documentation. You can also install `jingtrang` for more precise and useful validation messages

Comment: @Kenly I know :-)  I wrote this question and the answer below  precisely to document how to get the better error messages.  If there's a duplicate (I couldn't find one),  please flag this and I'll accept the duplicate suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message, at least on Debian Linux, is produced by [LXML's RelaxNG validator](https://lxml.de/validation.html#relaxng), which in turn relies on [libxml2](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/wikis/home).  We can see that [xmllint](https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/libxml2/xmllint.html), also based on `libxml2`,  produces the same output:

```bash
xmllint path/to/view.xml --relaxng ./odoo/odoo/import_xml.rng 
<snip xml file content/>
path/to/view.xml:3: element data: Relax-NG validity error : Element odoo has extra content: data
path/to/view.xml fails to validate
```

We can't easily change how Odoo is validating XML files, but we can install a different validator, [jing](https://github.com/relaxng/jing-trang), and use that to validate our file in the terminal.

To install (on Debian-based systems):

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install jing libbatik-java libavalon-framework-java
```

Once installed, call it like this and review the more detailed error message (formatted for readability):

```bash
jing ./odoo/odoo/import_xml.rng  path/to/view.xml

path/to/view.xml:23:9: error: attribute "view_model" not allowed here; expected attribute
 "auto_refresh", "context", "domain", "groups", "key2", "limit", "multi", "src_model", "target", "usage",
 "view_id", "view_mode" or "view_type"
```

Since Odoo 13, [there is optional support for using the jingtrang package to generate jing's validation error messages](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/16cd987a53bcc7c29af28b58bec8d8bf6cc1b9d7) in Odoo itself. To enable this support, install the [jingtrang module from pypi](https://pypi.org/project/jingtrang/).